# How to set unicode locale in R?

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have some special characters in my UTF-8 .R file and the attempt to run code as a file in the R command line returns `unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING`.

Meanwhile, the code runs okay line by line, say, in RStudio or Eclipse.

I suggest I need to change the locale via `Sys.setlocale(locale=)`, but all my attempts (including SO's answers) to find the right `locale` parameter for UTF-8 gave `OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored`. I can set up something like `Sys.setlocale(locale="English")`, but it doesn't help.

How to set up "UTF-8" on Windows?

Comment: Windows and cmd.exe and UTF-8 really don't mix.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Windows and software development don't mix in general. But maybe there're any workarounds to run unicode files in R? After all, it's a modest need.

Comment: No, Windows is a superb environment for software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to change to locale of your R to UTF-8 ([if that is even possible under windows](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-November/067944.html))

```
source(..., locale="UTF-8")
```

should do the trick. The R-script is then translated into your local locale.

Comment: Thanks, but that returns `unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING` to me. The error points at the line where non-ANSI characters appear first.

Comment: Right now I don't have access to a windows machine to et things on. However, I found the following answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding

Comment: Thanks, Jan. This helped. I used `eval(parse(filename, encoding="UTF-8"))`, though it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with an R file encoded in UTF-8.

I fixed it by running the script this way  :

```
Rscript --encoding=UTF-8 filename.R
```