# Weird Foreign Character Behavior in R / Rstudio

Tags: r, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, rstudio

I have a CSV with Czech characters in it that looks like this:

```
id,address,city
660999,Vršovická 10,Praha
676838,Valentova 50,Praha 4
676858,Husova 6740,Pardubice
677971,Lipová 10,Třebíč
678304,Jana Ziky 10/1955,Ostrava
...
```

When I import into RStudio everything looks fine if I view it using the View() function.

[image: View() in Rstudio]

But in the terminal when I view the values everything looks crazy.

```
xl = read.csv("some_csv.csv")
head(xl)

      id              address      city 
1 660999       VrÅ¡ovickÃ¡ 10     Praha     
2 676838         Valentova 50     Praha 4     
3 676858          Husova 6740   Pardubice     
4 677971           LipovÃ¡ 10     TÅ™ebÃ­Ä     
5 678304    Jana Ziky 10/1955   Ostrava
```

When I check the encoding with `Encoding(xl[1,2])` for example it says `"unknown"`.

I also have Russian data with the same exact problem.

I've tried switching to `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "czech")` and `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")` and importing under those settings and they behave the same.

I'm using Rstudio Version 0.98.501 with R version 3.0.2 on Windows 7.  A colleague on a separate computer is having the same problem.

Anything I can do make these characters work correctly the terminal?

Comment: ?read.csv you can choose the encoding to read in your csv, 'UTF-8' will probably work

Comment: Configure the Windows terminal for UTF-8 -- `chcp 65001`

Comment: Actually, the encoding to UTF-8 argument works for the CZ characters but not the Russian ones... weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to source() .R file saved using UTF-8 encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding)