# R changes nordic letter ä to Ã¤. Unknown reason

Tags: r, character-encoding

Suddenly after using roxygen, all ä letters (I'm living in scandinavia) gets outputted as the ugly Ã¤. Why? And how can this be fixed?

Comment: Show us your `sys.info()` and `sys.getlocale()`. A reproducible example would be useful as well.

Comment: There is no sys.info() or sys.getlocale() tried both and they both give no object found error. Don't know about reproducibility, but I was writing some documentation code when it started. All ä's look good in code, but when outputted they become the ugly version.

Comment: Excuse me, that was a typo. `Sys.info()`, and `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake): `UTF-8` encoding of `ä` character is `0xC2`,`0xA4` but in code page `ANSI 1252` each separate hexadecimal value represents respectively:  `0xC2`=`Ã` and  `0xA4`=`¤`. Not much more to say; perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5066790/3439404) could help.