# How to read non-english characters with read.delim in R?

Tags: r, character-encoding, non-english

I have a text file containing several languages, how to read in R use `read.delim` function,

```
Encoding("file.tsv")
#[1] "unknown"

source_data = read.delim(file, header= F, fileEncoding= "windows-1252",
               sep = "\t", quote = "")
source_D[360]
#[1] "ð¿ð¾ð¸ñðº ð½ð° ññ‚ð¾ð¼ ñð°ð¹ñ‚ðµ"
```

But the `source_D[360]` showed in Notepad is 'поиск на этом сайте'

Comment: I don't know: is this helpfull for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding ?

Comment: Have u tried changing encoding="UTF-8" ? Maybe it works

Answer (score 5):

tidyverse approach:

use the option `locale` in read_delim.
(readr functions have _ instead of . and are usually faster and smarter to read)
more details here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html#parsing-a-vector

```
source_data = read_delim(file, header= F, 
                         locale = locale(encoding = "windows-1252"),
                         sep = "\t", quote = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source_data = read.delim(file, header = F, sep = "\t", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Encoding(source_data)= "UTF-8"
```

I have tried, If you run you R in windows, above code works for me.
and if you run R in Unix, you could use following code

```
source_data = read.delim(file, header = F, fileEncoding="UTF-8", sep = "\t", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```