# Why does R source() sometimes work and sometimes gives an error

Tags: r

I have the API credentials in one separate R script to keep it out of Git. I want to run this script in the beginning of the scripts that actually interact with the different servers. I have successfully used the same strategy for all my global functions.

```
setwd("G:/script")
source("API_credentials.R")  # gives always an error 

# > source("API_credentials.R")
# Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""g:\s"

source("ProVeg_functions.R") # runs fine
```

**Problem:**

Why does the first *source()* not work, while the second one does?  The error message does not make any sense to me.

**Solutions tried:**

1. I have tried different escape chars \.
2. I have tried writing full path & file names.
3. I have tried putting the file name in as a variable, which gets its
   content from a *dir()* search, to make sure that the file exists and
   the name is correctly written.
4. Order of *source()* does not change situation.
5. Isolating the piece of code with error, and restarting R.
6. upgraded all my packages and R to version 4.0.2.
7. The API_credentials.r script works fine when run on its own. the *Sys.setenv()* works fine and I can read the API keys with *Sys.getenv()*.
8. I am not sure if it is related to my problem, but if I do *usethis::edit_r_environ()* I can not see my API keys.

**Setup**
Windows 10, R-Studio 1.3.1093, R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)

Comment: have you tried running `traceback()` after the error? It gives the full sequence of errors and can help pinpoint what in the file is causing the problem. I have had issues with uncommon characters before. I think I followed advice in the following link e.g. adding `encoding="utf-8"`, but this may be a different issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding

Comment: @Jonny Yes, I have tried 'traceback()', but it does not provide any useful info. It says only:   '1: source("API_credentials.R")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly assumed that the error message was related to the script calling the API_credentials.R, but it actually was an error message indicating an error in the API_credentials.R script.  Fixed a typo and all is good.