# Read txt-file with R commands into a list in R

Tags: r

#R--version: 4.1.1

Say I have a .txt-file with the content

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(4,5,6)
```

and I want to read those statements into a list `l` such that

`l = list(a = c(1,2,3),b=(4,5,6))`

e.g

```
l = read_into_list_func("path/to/file/my_file.txt")

l$a
#1 2 3 

l$b
#4 5 6
```

I know how to read a txt-file but the issue is that instead of getting the command `a=c(1,2,3)` I get the string `'a=c(1,2,3)'`.

Comment: So the text file contains arbitrary R commands? Or is the structure entirely fixed?

Comment: I write the file my self (generated from a python-script), but the structure is fixed as above, i.e containing a list-creation at each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, you can parse and evaluate the file as R code inside an environment, and convert that into a list:

```
e = new.env()
eval(parse('path/to/file.txt'), envir = e, encoding = 'UTF-8')
l = as.list(e)
```

([Don’t use `source`, it fails on Windows for non-ANSI encodings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588488/1968))

… however, this is fairly inefficient and, more importantly, **unsafe**, because it executes arbitrary R code that’s in that file. If the file is provided by a malicious source and contains code to delete all your files, you do *not* want to execute that. Only use the above code for files of known, benign provenance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since I write the txt-file my self, that shouldn't be safety issue