# RStudio fails when run through "Source as Local Job"

Tags: r, rstudio

The code consists in two files:

`caller.R`:

```
a <- 1
source("s1.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
b <- fa()
```

`s1.R`:

```
fa <- function() {
  a*2
}
```

This code runs smoothly when `caller.R` is sourced (Crtl+Shift+S) in RStudio IDE, providing the correct expected result `b=2`.

However, when `caller.R` is sourced through "Source as Local Job...", it throws an error (Portuguese), meaning that execution was interrupted because it was not able to find object 'a':

```
Error in fa() : objeto 'a' n�o encontrado
Calls: sourceWithProgress -> eval -> eval -> fa
Execu��o interrompida
```

I have tried all possible "Source as Local Job..." options combinations ("Run job with copy of global environments, etc.) without success.

What do I have to do to be able to run caller.R as a local job?

Comment: Based on the Unicode rubbish you’re running Windows. Be aware that `source(…, encoding = 'utf-8')` [is broken on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588488/1968)! Use `eval(parse(…, encoding = 'utf-8'))` instead.

Comment: And, as mentioned below the answer, it would be better to rewrite your `s1.R` in such a way that it no longer relies on external state. Have a look at [‘box’ modules](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) for a slightly different and (IMHO, though I’m biased) vastly superior approach.

Comment: In RStudio, *"a “local job” is an R script that runs in a separate, dedicated R session"* ([ref](https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/03/14/rstudio-1-2-jobs/)). Variables in one R session are not available in another R session; this is not unique to R, it is how process-management (and security and encapsulation and ...) works. This is a new process, not a new thread (which might support what you want, albeit R and threads is still not great). I second Konrad's comment: write your function so that it doesn't effect scope-breach.

Comment: As such, I think this is two things: (1) not understanding that "source as a local job" runs the script in a completely new, untarnished, unprepped R session, so the script file needs to initialize *everything* needed (data, packages, functions, etc); and this is highlighted by (2) an anti-pattern of a `function` that breaks reproducibility and does not adhere to *functional programming* fundamentals. Fix #2 and the symptom goes away; understand #1 and internalize #2 and your programming becomes much more robust/resilient :-)

Comment: @r2evans I think you’re misunderstanding the error description: both scripts are executed in the *same* R process. Yes, there’s a new process when launching a script as a local job; but that process runs `caller.R` which, in turn, sources `s1.R`. All in the same process.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, yup, I missed that detail, thank you.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for the utf-8 issue warning, and the box package suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have it available in the same environment, you can try to use the local = TRUE

```
source("s1.R", encoding = "UTF-8", local = TRUE)
```

Comment: That’s a good workaround. A better solution would obviously be to write `s1.R` such that it doesn’t rely on external state.

Comment: Solved! Many thanks.